# Extracting multiple values of varying sizes from a string

Tags: c#, string, split

I have example two strings like so

```
var string1 = "order customer joe intel 300";
var string2 = "order customer john amd 200";
```

I am trying to create a method that can extract the name, the company and the number from each string and form a formatted string from the data. For example

```
var formattedString1 = "Order placed for joe - 300 units of intel"
```

So far I've managed to remove the words `order` and `customer` like this

```
string1 = string1.Replace("order", string.Empty).Replace("customer", string.Empty);
```

My question is how can I extract the remaining the words from the string and save them as variables like this

```
var name = "joe";
var company = "intel";
var quantity = "300";
```

Note that I am trying to form a solution that will correctly extract the name, company and number from any string regardless of the length of any variables.

Comment: split on the space, take the last three, join or store in a class as needed

Comment: Without some form of consistency, it will be extremely difficult. One consistency I see is that the info you need is in the last 3 words. Thus you can try and `Split` the string using a space and then get the last 3 words. However, I am not sure if your data will have that consistency all the time.

Comment: yeah once you split this into an array, you can just skip the first two values, either of the answers below should work for ya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's 'my feeling' that you're new to programming, so I will give you details on how to do it. As mentioned in the comments you can use [String.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2) method which will return a String Array. Each string in the array can be captured using the index, which starts at 0. You can then use the indexes to assign variables to the strings and format it.

Something like this:

```
string string1 = "order customer joe intel 300";
string string2 = "order customer john amd 200";

string[] parts = string1.Split(' ');

string name = parts[2];
string company = parts[3]
string quantity = parts[4];

string formattedString = "Order placed for " + name + " - " + quantity + " units of " + company;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have lots of these strings that you want to process, which it sounds like you do .. You could try something like this:

```
// Array of data
string[] values = 
    {
    "order customer joe intel 300",
    "order customer john amd 200",
    "order customer bob Qualcomm 300"
};

// Loop the array of data
foreach (string value in values)
{
    // split up the data in to the words
    string[] split = value.Split(' ');

    // Get the values (assuming they are always in the same place)
    string name = split[2];
    string company = split[3];
    string quantity = split[4];

    // Create the formatted string
    string formattedString = $"Order placed for {name} - {quantity} units of {company}";

    // Do something with the string ..
    Console.WriteLine(formattedString);
}
```